# making a manipulation inside DB

Tags: php, mysql

hii all..i have some code that make all string characters which have been input into DB change to capital size..this is my code:

```
function newinputdata($modelnm,$serialno)

$Model=mysql_real_escape_string($modelnm);
$Serial_number=mysql_real_escape_string($serialno);
$str=strtoupper($str)
echo $str;

$sql="INSERT INTO.........";
```

is that true?

Comment: where is $str getting its original value from?

Comment: your code has some unrelated elements...

Comment: @all: i'm still confuse how to manipulate all value..the value is $model and $serial..i don't know how to combine "strtoupper"...please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm that won't work, as you did not define `$str`

Do instead:

```
$Model = mysql_real_escape_string($modelnm);
$Serial_number = mysql_real_escape_string($serialno);
$Model = strtoupper($Model)
$Serial_number = strtoupper($Serial_number);
```

Of course this assume that `$Serial_number` contains characters, otherwise it's useless to capitalise it (and to escape it with `mysql_real_escape_string`, just cast it to `int`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
$str=strtoupper($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no sense, but assuming that you want to change everything that you put into the database to upper case, this is how you would do it:

```
function insert_data($model_number, $serial_number) {
  $model_number = strtoupper($model_number);
  $serial_number = strtoupper($serial_number);

  $values = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($model_number) . "',"
          . "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($serial_number). "'";

  $q = "INSERT INTO dataTable `modelColumn`, `serialColumn` values ($values);"

  echo "I would run the query $q";

 }
```

Of course replace table name and column names to taste :)